# Ember-i18n location fallback

Tags: javascript, ember.js, internationalization, ember-i18n

I am trying to introduce `ember-i18n` into my current project to manage translations across different varieties of english. Specifically, aiming to handle `en-US` & general `en` words. The issue I am having is that even if I specify the `i18n.locale` to be `en-US` it still uses the translations form the `en/translations.js` file. This is happening even if the `defaultLocale` is set to `en-US` in the *config/environment.js*

I have specified two translation files:

```
locales/
├── en
│   └── translations.js
└── en-US
    └── translations.js
```

with the following contents:

*app/locales/en/translations.js*

```
export default {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  cheque: 'Cheque',                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  province: 'Province',                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  postalCode: 'Postal Code',                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
};
```

*app/locales/en-US/translations.js*

```
export default {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  cheque: 'Check',                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  province: 'State',                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  postalCode: 'Zip Code',                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
};
```

Any ideas why the I can't get the location fallback to work as intended?

#### references:

[Ember-i18n Wiki - Location Fallback](https://github.com/jamesarosen/ember-i18n/wiki/Doc:-Defining-Translations#location-fallback)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

James A. Rosen answered my question in this [tweet](https://twitter.com/jamesarosen/status/724771123208974336). The issue was that the folder needs to be lower case (`en-us` instead of `en-US`).

> The default Ember-CLI resolver downcases all module names.

Because it didn't recognize that I had an `en-us` folder it was defaulting to the `en` translations.